# Как использовать методы класса из импортируемого своего модуля?

Tags: python

Я создал свой класс в отдельном файле MyMath.py

Вот его код

```
import math
from abc import ABC

class MyMath(ABC):
    """Абстрактный класс MyMath"""

    @classmethod
    def circle_len(cls, radius: int) -> float:
        return 2 * math.pi * radius

    @classmethod
    def circle_sq(cls, radius: int) -> float:
        return math.pi * radius ** 2

    @classmethod
    def cube_value(cls, edge: int) -> float:
        return edge ** 3

    @classmethod
    def sphere_area(cls, radius: int) -> float:
        return 4 * math.pi * radius ** 2
```

С помощью import MyMath импортирую его в файл main.py . Они лежат в одной директории.

Как мне использовать методы класса MyMath?

На данный момент при написании:

```
import MyMath

res_1 = MyMath.circle_len(radius=5)
print(res_1)

res_2 = MyMath.circle_sq(radius=6)
print(res_2)

res_3 = MyMath.cube_value(edge=6)
print(res_3)

res_4 = MyMath.sphere_area(radius=6)
print(res_4)
```

выходит ошибка AttributeError: module 'MyMath' has no attribute 'circle_len'

не видит аттрибутов

Comment: Попробуйте `from MyMath import MyMath`. Сейчас получается у вас `MyMath` - это модуль, а не класс в этом модуле. И лучше называть как-то немного по-разному модуль и класс, как-раз чтобы не путаться. Ну либо писать двойное такое обращение `MyMath.MyMath.circle_len`.

Comment: Нет, не получается

Comment: А что пишет? Ошибка должна быть уже другая в этом случае.